# Rails 6 - Sortable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a problem with HTML sortable update in rails 6 
I want to drag and drop the images through web page and that is worked fine but, When I want to update the order I got 404 not found error in console log and also an error in find ID.
by the way, I use this script for HTML sortable
https://github.com/jordanhudgens/devcamp-portfolio/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/html.sortable.js

Controller :

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_portfolio_item, only:[:edit , :show, :update , :destroy]
  layout "portfolio"
  access all: [:show, :index , :angular], user: {except: [:destroy, :new , :create , :update , :edit , :sort]}, site_admin: :all
    def index
        # You can filter what you want to show in protfolio
        # Portfolio.where(subtitle: "Angular")
        # You can define it in models and call the method here
        # It must create on Portfolio.rb in models
        # You can create scope too on models and call
        @portfolio_items = Portfolio.by_position
    end
    def angular
      @angular_portfolio_items = Portfolio.angular
    end
    def sort
      params[:order].each do |key, value|
        Portfolio.find(value[:id]).update(position: value[:position])
      end
      head :ok
    end
    def new
      @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new
      3.times { @portfolio_item.technologies.build }
    end
    def create
      @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        if @portfolio_item.save
          format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully created.' }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
        end
      end
      end
    def edit
    end
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @portfolio_item.update(portfolio_params)
          format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record was successfully updated.' }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
        end
      end
    end
    def show
    end
    def destroy
      # Perform the lookup
      # Destroy/delete the record
      @portfolio_item.destroy
      #Redirect
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to portfolios_url, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully deleted!.' }
    end
  end
    private
    def portfolio_params
      params.require(:portfolio)
    end
    def set_portfolio_item
      @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
    end
    end
```

This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  resources :portfolios, except: [:show] do
    put :sort, on: :collection
  end
  get 'portfolio/:id' , to: 'portfolios#show', as: 'portfolio_show'
  get 'angular-items' , to: 'portfolios#angular'
  # we can pass anything here after get
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'contact', to: 'pages#contact'
  resources :blogs do
    member do
      get :toggle_status
    end
  end
  resources :posts
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

This is my CoffeeScript for HTML sortable

```
ready = undefined
set_positions = undefined

set_positions = ->
  $('.card').each (i) ->
    $(this).attr 'data-pos', i + 1
    return
  return

ready = ->
  set_positions()
  $('.sortable').sortable()
  $('.sortable').sortable().bind 'sortupdate', (e, ui) ->
    updated_order = []
    set_positions()
    $('.card').each (i) ->
      updated_order.push
        id: $(this).data('id')
        position: i + 1
      return
    $.ajax
      type: 'PUT'
      url: '/portfolios/sort'
      data: order: updated_order
    return
  return

$(document).ready ready
```

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: [1] pry(#<PortfoliosController>)> continue
{"0"=>{"position"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"position"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"position"=>"3"}, "3"=>{"position"=>"4"}, "4"=>{"position"=>"5"}, "5"=>{"position"=>"6"}, "6"=>{"position"=>"7"}, "7"=>{"position"=>"8"}, "8"=>{"position"=>"9"}, "9"=>{"position"=>"10"}, "10"=>{"position"=>"11"}, "11"=>{"position"=>"12"}, "12"=>{"position"=>"13"}, "13"=>{"position"=>"14"}, "14"=>{"position"=>"15"}, "15"=>{"position"=>"16"}, "16"=>{"position"=>"17"}, "17"=>{"position"=>"18"}}

Comment: Completed 404 Not Found in 6967ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 12437)

 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Portfolio without an ID):
  
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:19:in `block in sort'
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:18:in `sort'

Comment: The each of position , I've sent that in first comment

Comment: if I change find to where then value[:id] have value and update all position but when I refresh the page the order will back to normal `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Portfolio without an ID):
  
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:18:in `block in sort`
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:17:in `sort`